# How to copy paste data in row to bottom of data set based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get data from A2:F2,H2 to paste to the bottom of my dataset  based on if there's text in column H, then column I, then column J. Right now I'm getting all rows (criteria not working).

```
Public Sub CopyRows()
Sheets("Exposure Distribution").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column H
    ThisValue = Cells(x, 8).Value
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText("x, 8") = "True" Then
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets("Exposure Distribution").Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Exposure Distribution").Select
    End If
Next x
```

I expect only the rows where there is text in the cell to paste to the bottom of the dataset, so then the final result would be from A2:G2, and G2 at the bottom would be the value from H2 at the top.

Comment: Do you mean to check if the cell is text? Because `IsText("x, 8") ` is always true. Do you mean `IsText(ThisValue)`?

Comment: I'm trying to copy paste whether the cell contains text, so yes. Now how could I get it to automatically paste A2:F2 and H2 at the bottom? Thanks for the help!